# Some chars read as a question mark (?) from a file on Java

Tags: java, file, encoding, character-encoding, ascii

I'm developing a app which opens a file and writes its content in another existing file with adifferent name.

The problem is that some chars, which don't exist in ASCII(I think), for example (char)144 or (char)154, are replaced by (char)63 or the *** question mark ->?.

I have tried to change VM charset but the problem is not solved.
Here the part of the code we are interested in:

```
File out = new File("new_clientK.swf");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("input.swf")));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(out));
    String line = null;
    //The first line is edited
    line = reader.readLine();
    writer.append(line.replace(oldstring, newstring));
    writer.append((char) 10);
    //The first line is added, now, I get all the remaining code and add it 
    //char by char
    int charnum = 0;
    while ((charnum = reader.read()) != -1) {
        
        writer.append((char) (charnum));
    }

    reader.close();
    writer.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you should not use a **text oriented API** like *BufferedReader/PrintWriter* but some raw binary API like *FileInputStream/FileOutputStream*.

Because you can't even play with **encoding**, a SWF file is not a document and contains raw binary data.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. If it works/doesn't works I will notice you.

Comment: The simplest method, if your file is not too big, is to use a "MemoryStream" and its "getBytes" method to obtain a byte[] that is the raw representation of the file.

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution of my problem.